# Dynamically place submenu list to top or bottom using pure HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

I have created a menu - submenu option using pure CSS and it is working as expected i.e on hovering on the main menu item submenu is getting displayed but the issue is when the option is at the last of the page the submenu options are going to the bottom of the page something as follow :

[image]

What I'm expecting is if we don't have space at the bottom the menu should be displayed in the top position something as follows , that is it should place itself based on the space available
[image]

HTML

```css
.main-item {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.main-item li:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

.dropdown-item {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #6c757d;
  border-color: #6c757d;
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: #6c757d;
    border-color: #6c757d;
    color: #fff;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="main-item p-0">
  <li>
    <button type="button" class="btn-xs btn-outline-primary">Options</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="dropdown-submenu dropdown-item dropdown-toggle">
        Menu 2
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown-item">1. sub-menu1</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">2. sub-menu2</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">3. sub-menu3</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">4. sub-menu4</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">5. sub-menu5</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">6. sub-menu6</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">7. sub-menu7</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">8. sub-menu8</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">9. sub-menu9</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Pure css can't detect whether you have enough room.  You could use media queries but you would need to know the height of the dropdown and calculate your media queries based on that, but if the height changes you would need to change all your media queries (and if you have multiple dropdowns, you would need to add a media query for each of them).  Also I don't see why the width of the browser would affect the top or bottom position

Comment: FWIW, CSS Container Queries will probably allow for this, but they're still quite a ways off from reaching recommended status or broad support in browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use a scrollbar for long menus, so I added some attributes to the `.dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu` class:

```css
.main-item {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.main-item li:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  width: fit-content;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.dropdown-item {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #6c757d;
  border-color: #6c757d;
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: #6c757d;
    border-color: #6c757d;
    color: #fff;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="main-item p-0">
  <li>
    <button type="button" class="btn-xs btn-outline-primary">Options</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="dropdown-submenu dropdown-item dropdown-toggle">
        Menu 2
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown-item">1. sub-menu1</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">2. sub-menu2</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">3. sub-menu3</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">4. sub-menu4</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">5. sub-menu5</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">6. sub-menu6</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">7. sub-menu7</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">8. sub-menu8</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">9. sub-menu9</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```